# Persisting serialized object in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Sample model:

```
/** @Entity */
class Person{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column  */
    protected $name;

    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    protected $created_at;

   //setters and getters...

   public function __construct($std){
        $this->id = $std->id;
        $this->nome = $std->nome;
        $this->created_at = new DateTime;
   }
}
```

I'm using json to comunicate between client/server.
I need to get the json from the client

```
{ "id": 123, "name": "john" }
```

and persist, keeping the field "created_at" unchanged. Doing like this:

```
$p = json_decode($string);
$person = new Person($p);
entity_manager->merge($person);
entity_manager->flush();
```

In this case the object is updated successfully, BUT, obviously, the "created_at" field is set with the new value from "new DateTime".
I could get a managed entity from the DB and then just change the "name", but I don´t want the unnecessary Select..

In a nutshell, how can I perform something like this:

```
UPDATE Person set name = "john" where id = 123
```

Is there an annotation to ignore a property on update?
Is there a way to set a property as unchanged?

EDIT

After a couple of tests using the SqlLogger, I realized that the method merge() executes a SELECT to get the current state...
So, my solution, for now, is to get the object myself and replace only the values I wanna update. Something like:

```
$std = json_decode($string);
$p = entity_manager->find('Person', $std->id);
$p->name = $std->name;
entity_managet->flush();
```

This way the number of "selects" is the same, but I get to keep the original values from attributes that I don't get from json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine needs a persisted entity to be able to define which field have been updated or not.

http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/doctrine/doctrine2.git/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.UnitOfWork.html#607-623

If your issue is only about a DateTime, you can use the "columnDefinition" part of "Column" annotation to handle your create_at value.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column

For example with mysql :

```
/** @Column(type="datetime", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP") */
protected $created_at;

//setters and getters...

public function __construct($std){
    $this->id = $std->id;
    $this->nome = $std->nome;
    //And so remove this initialization
    //$this->created_at = new DateTime;
}
```

Comment: The problem of using the column definition is that the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP flag is limited to just one column per table... you can't use it to automatically set the created timestamp and the last updated timestamp.

Comment: I accepted because of the obvious 1st sentence: "Doctrine needs a persisted entity...". It led me to do more tests and find out that merge() also performs a select in DB.